# Expression of a function in spherical coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I want to get the expression for a function in cartesian coordinates. 
The function should have the following properties:

1. It should have a minimum at r=R (in spherical coordinates)
2. It should increase like a parabola in both x and y direction away from R.

How do I go about constructing such a function?

Answer (score 1):

So you would like a function of the form $(r-R)^2$ in spherical coordinate.
Since $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, you can consider 
$$
f(x,y) = (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - R)^2
$$
See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5B(Sqrt%5Bx%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%5D-2)%5E2,%7Bx,-3,3%7D,%7By,-3,3%7D%5D) for the plot at $R=2$.

Note also that you can smooth the peak at the origin by removing the square root. This will however make the function grow as "$x^4$" away from the origin.

---

Ok maybe something too complicated. The idea is to use the simple $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ but dig a trench at radius $R$.

The "trench"-function can be $-De^{-(x^2 + y^2- R^2)^2}$ where $D$ is the depth of the hole. (Try to plot it !), it is mostly zero except in the annulus of radius $R$ where is goes to $-D$. Then we define :
$$
f(x,y) = -De^{-(x^2 + y^2- R^2)^2}+(x^2 + y^2)
$$
To make sure that the minimum is indeed achieved in the annulus and not at the origin, we need to make the hole deep enough, for example setting $D=R^2 + 1$.

[Plot here](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=-(4%2B1)*e%5E(-(x%5E2%2By%5E2-4)%5E2)%2B(x%5E2%2By%5E2)&xRange=-3%2C3&yRange=-3%2C3&resolution=25) (with $R=2$). We see that the function reaches $-1$ in the hole and no ugly peak at the origin. Also this function has the advantage that it is really close $x^2 + y^2$ everywhere (before and after the trench).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this too. But this function becomes really pointed near the origin. Is there a way to smoothen this down?